# Using a Excel Userform to cut a row that has "x," delete row, and paste in different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, paste, userform

Working on having a userform in Excel that will cut a row with a value in column "B" that is input on the userform, then paste the row in sheet2 while also adding 3 more values from the user form. This is what I have but currently it's doing nothing for me:

```
Private Sub OkButton2_Click()

Dim i As Long: i = 1
With ActiveSheet
    For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        If .Cells(n, "B") = "ChartTextBox2.Value" Then
            .Cells(n, "B").EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(i, "A")
            .Cells(n, "B").EntireRow.Delete
            i = i + 1
'Transfer information
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = DTPicker4.Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = DispoTextBox.Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = ReasonTextBox.Value
        End If
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(emptyRow, Sheet2, 11)` isn't how you use it. Do you mean `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow,11)`?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine for me. Are you comparing with text `"ChartTextBox2.Value"` or with the text in the textbox `ChartTextBox2`? Assuming you are comparing with the text in the textbox, below code works fine for me. Also in your code `nLastRow` and `nFirstRow` were not declared. If this is not the case you can remove these statements.

```
Private Sub OkButton2_Click()
  Dim nLastRow As Long  'If already declared neglect this statement
  Dim nFirstRow As Long 'If already declared neglect this statement
  Dim i As Long: i = 1

  nLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count   'If already specified neglect this statement
  nFirstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row         'If already specified neglect this statement

  With ActiveSheet
    For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
      If .Cells(n, "B") = ChartTextBox2.Value Then
        .Cells(n, "B").EntireRow.Cut Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A")
        .Cells(n, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        i = i + 1
        'Transfer information
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = DTPicker4.Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = DispoTextBox.Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = ReasonTextBox.Value
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Still not working for me :( driving my crazy, I can't find what's hanging it up. No bug... just no anything :P Comparing with the text in the textbox ChartTextBox2.

Comment: Try commenting most of the statements and uncomment one statement one after the other. This may help. Did you try putting break point and debugging with F8 ?

Comment: When I used the debugger (using break points) it looks like where I'm getting caught up is an endless loop:

        If .Cells(n, "B") = ChartTextBox2.Value Then
        End If
        Next
        If .Cells(n, "B") = ChartTextBox2.Value

Comment: Check the values of nLastRow, nFirstRow  and emptyRow. Still the for loop should not make it endless loop. By the way, I think you need to change the value of emptyRow in the for loop as this cell is overwritten every time. It depends on the row you want to write in Sheet2. may be in next row. In such case it will be Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow + i, 7).Value = DTPicker4.Value